# Удаление элемента динамического массива

Tags: c++, ооп

Помогите, пожалуйста! Выдаёт ошибку:

> E0852  выражение должно представлять собой указатель на полный тип объекта

Сам код:

```
{
private:
    string name; // найменування
    float price; // ціна
    size_t area; // розмір
    string address; // адреса
    string facilities; // зручності
    string repair; // ремонт
    long int phone_num; // номер телефону
public:
    void print_inf();
    void input();
    void price_increase();
    bool conditions();
    string get_name();

    immovables();
    immovables(string name, float price, size_t area, string address, string facilities, string repair, long int phone_num);
    immovables(const immovables& imm);
    ~immovables() {};
};

class show
{
public:
    immovables* getImm();

    void print_inf();
    void input();
    void price_increase();
    void conditions();
    void delete_found();
    //immovables* del_element(int len, int num);

    show();
    show(immovables* imm, size_t num, string client_fname, string agent_fname, string date_show, string result);
    show(const show& sh);
    ~show();

private:
    immovables* imm;
    size_t num;
    string client_fname;
    string agent_fname;
    string date_show;
    string result;
};
```

Сама функция, где появляется ошибка:

```
void show::delete_found()
{
    int choice;
    cout << " Оберіть критерій, за яким бажаєте видалити запис (1 - найменування, 2 - ціна, 3 - розмір, 4 - адреса, 5 - зручності, 6 - ремонт, 7 - номер телефону)." << endl;
    cout << " Ваш вибір => ";
    cin >> choice;
    switch (choice)
    {
    case 1:
        string str;
        cout << " Введіть найменування: ";
        cin >> str;
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        {
            if (imm[i].get_name() == str)
                delete imm[i];
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Как мне удалить только один элемент? Спасибо!

Comment: Сделать новый массив размером на 1 меньше. В цикле скопировать туда все элементы, кроме удаляемого. Удалить старый массив целиком.

Comment: Оператор `delete` принимает указатель на объект или массив объектов. Вы же передаёте ему объект типа `immovables`. Чтобы удалить один объект, либо сделайте, как посоветовал @HolyBlackCat, либо, если это для Вас не критично, замените массив на `std::vector` и используйте `erase`, по-моему это лучший вариант. Если же хотите просто удалить один объект в массиве, можно конечно сделать `delete (imm+i)`, но **так делать не стоит**, ибо, как минимум, в массиве на месте этого объекта останется невалидный кусок памяти (сдвиг не произойдёт автоматически) и также это может стать причиной других проблем.

Comment: `delete (imm+i)` вызовет краш, почти наверняка.

Comment: @V-Mor *"можно конечно сделать delete (imm+i)"* - простите, но не давайте неверные советы. в `delete` можно передавать только указатель, полученный с помощью `new`.

Comment: Прошу прощения. Действительно, `delete (imm+i)`, было неверно.

Comment: Вообще то, в первую очередь, старайтесь правильно(понятно, логично)  классифицировать. Нельзя взять и говорить, например, что картина, сапог, лом, лопата и скрипка могут составить некую сущность. Вообще то можно, но нормальные люди вас не поймут.. Во вторых научитесь  логично  строить абстракцию и  инкапсулировать данные.  Тогда у вас получится класс, объекты которого могут  быть полезными, а не набор любых  данных и функций, что у вас и наблюдается...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как я понимаю, вы для

```
immovables* imm;
```

выделяете целый массив. А теперь просто расскажите, как вы себе это представляете: есть выделенная большая область памяти

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|     |     |     |     |     |     |     | 
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
^ - сюда указывает imm
                  ^- это элемент imm[i]
```

Если не трудно - расскажите, что вы хотите получить - ну, как должна выглядеть память, например - после вызова `delete imm[i];`? Что должно произойти?

*Подсказка - этот код вообще не компилируется, потому что тип `imm[i]` не указатель!*

Но, допустим, вы написали `delete &imm[i]` и компилятор пропускает выражение - так вот, как вы себе представляете результат этого действия?

Вероятно, это не полный ответ, но который заставит вас задуматься - а значит, *понять* причину неприятностей.

Конечно, с дидактической точки зрения применение массивов оправдано - ну, просто чтобы научиться с ними работать. Но в данном случае применение `vector` существенно упростило бы задачу удаления - потому что при работе с массивом и удалении из него надо либо помечать элемент как удаленный и больше с ним не работать, либо выполнять сдвиг элементов справа влево и хранить общее количество имеющихся элементов. Что вектор делает автоматически...